# captcha image is not visible in php

Tags: php, gd, captcha

I have pre installed GD library and Freetype library in centos server.
I am not able to see captcha image.

ERROR:

```
Call to undefined function imagettfbbox() in /path/public_html/captcha/securimage.php
```

What could be the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably didn't install it properly.

Comment: If you look at the output of `phpinfo();`, do you see both extensions?

Comment: I can see GD extension. I can not see Freetype. But, in command line it says it's already installed.

Comment: command line != web server. They can both have different php.ini files.

Comment: I am connected with SSH

Comment: What OS / Linux flavor are you on and did you compile PHP manually or was it installed by a package manager?  It needs to be compiled `--with-freetype` in order to work.  Also you need to have libfreetype installed, so on Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` or RedHat/CentOS `yum install freetype-devel`, then configure PHP to use freetype, or install the package manager's PHP GD extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **reCAPTCHA**. 
**In some hosting servers, GD based captcha doesn't work. I have experienced it.** 
reCAPTCHA can be used with out GD library.
It loads captcha images from a external service and validates using public key cryptography.
So **NO** internal generation of captcha images. 
Very easy to use.

**E.G:**

**Front End :**

```
<html>
    <body> <!-- the body tag is required or the CAPTCHA may not show on some browsers -->
      <!-- your HTML content -->

      <form method="post" action="verify.php">
        <?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>

      <!-- more of your HTML content -->
    </body>
  </html>
```

**Back End Validation :**

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

For More info Visit : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php